# How to handle the stream closure in database clients when using stream<>?

Tags: sql, database, ballerina

What's the protocol for using `query()` and the returned `stream<>`? What are the exact cases where they need to be closed explicitly?

Also the docs on the `sql:Client` type says calling `close()` on that closes the client and shuts down the pool (See: https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerinax/mysql/1.6.1/clients/Client#close). I'm not sure whether it is the correct approach. The pool is shared so there's no concept of shutting down the pool, unless its a private pool?

Answer (score 0):

The `stream<>` object returned from the database clients are closed by the client when,

1. The stream is fully iterated.
   This is the recommended approach by using from var variable in stream
   Note:  If the user uses next() and does not fully iterate the stream, the stream needs to be closed by invoking close method.
2. The iteration of stream encounters an error.

Yes, `client.close()` shuts down the pool. This will make the client unable to perform any more operations. A `sql:Client` once initiated should be used be used throughout the entirety of the program. `close()` method should be used for graceful shutdowns.

Please find the best practice guide for Ballerina SQL client in https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/wso2/articles/74843098/guidelines-and-best-practices-for-ballerina-sql-client-usages